# Troubleshooting WebPI 5.0 Dependency Issues (It wants to bring in an old PHP version)

Tags: php, iis, iis-8

I am working on a Windows 2012 R2 Server with IIS 8 installed, now I am trying to get PHP 7.1.1 (x64) installed using the Web Platform Installer and am running into a dependency issue I am unsure how to troubleshoot.

After launching WebPI I click on Products and select "PHP 7.1.1 (x64)", then I click Install. After that the Prerequisites screen comes up and tells me that the following 3 items need to be installed.

- Windows Cache Extension 2.0 (x64) for PHP 7.1
- PHP 7.1.1 (x64)
- PHP Manager for IIS

This is exactly what I would expect, but after I click the "I Accept" button it immediately goes to "Downloading PHP 5.3.28" which is not the version of PHP I requested. I don't want multiple versions of PHP installed so I am trying to determine just what is pulling in PHP 5.3.28.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for determining just what might be pulling the old version of PHP in? I have dug through the WebPI log file and I do see this line...

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'PHP53
```

But I just don't understand why this old version of PHP is being pulled in.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

Firstly do not worry about multiple versions of PHP on an IIS Server. The module PHP Manager will allow you to configure which PHP you are using. Though by default in the scenario you have explained, the PHP 7.1 will be the default.

I believe that the last installable or executable version of a PHP installer that PHP provided was 5.3. I suspect that WPI needs bits from the 5.3 installer in order to facilitate the installation of subsequent versions of PHP in WPI such as 5.6, 7.0 and 7.1. This seems strange and Microsoft should not do things this way but as a long time user of IIS and PHP, I have not found any problem or issue with allowing WPI to do what it wants.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had ended up doing exactly what you recommended, I just gave in and let it install what it wanted to and all seems fine. In the long run it turned out that I did not even really need to install PHP at all because we are primarily using IIS for serving FileMaker databases on this machine and as it turned out FileMaker Server installed it's own version of PHP which is actually the one we ended up using.